# Asp.NET Web Api server returns 500 due to model binder issues for complex type

Tags: asp.net, exception, viewmodel, content-type, asp.net-web-api

If I pass in a correctly formatted viewmodel to a web api controller, but with the content-type set anything but xml or json, the server will return 500, saying there are no model binder for the type with the specified content-type. Sounds reasonable.

However, I would like to intercept that exception and return something like "400 - Content-type not supported". How can I make that happen? Is it ok to do even?